# How to print pop-up window contents along with main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, popup

I am developing a simple jQuery based web application calculator in which 5 pop-up windows with their contents appear. But at last when I click the print button of main window, only the content of main window is printed out. But I need to print all the pop-up window contents along with main window. I have searched it on Google but didn't get any effective answer.

Here is my printing function:

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    if (window.print) {
       document.write('<form> ' + '<input type=button name=print value="Print" '
                        + 'onClick="javascript:window.print();"></form>');
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript popup windows are closed when you call the `window.print()`, so obviously they won't be printed this way.

You could do it in various forms, for all of them you'd most likely have to create a function for the print button's `onclick` event.

The simplest would be copying the 5 pop ups' html to inside a hidden div in the bottom of the document which you can copy to through JQuery's `.html()` and then call the `.show()` on that div before sending the `window.print()` and hiding the div right after.

The function for the print button's onclick event could be something like:

```
function printpage()
{
    $('#hiddendiv').html($('#popupContact_1').html() + '<br />' +  $('#popupContact_2').html() + '<br />' +  $('#popupContact_3').html() +  '<br />' + $('#popupContact_4').html() + '<br />' +  $('#popupContact_5').html());
    $('#hiddendiv').show();
    window.print();
    $('#hiddendiv').hide();
}
```

Don't forget to create a div in the bottom of the document with `id=hiddendiv` and `style="display:none"` and calling the `printpage()` function in the print button's onclick event before trying this function. =)

You could also just call a `.show()` for each of your popup divs with `$('.a').show()` and place them at an absolute position of your page - iterating through them with `.each` to add a top value higher than the previous - before calling the `.print()`.

Comment: It is nicely working :)) Thanks a lot.you have solved my problem.